# Why does my navbar in mobile view look so skinny with the bulma framework?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bulma

I'm creating a mobile web app with ruby on rails and the bulma framework and I'm trying to figure out why my screens don't seem responsive. Has anyone ran into this problem before?[Here is what my application looks like in mobile view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U3Uo.png)

[I would like my application to be responsive like this in mobile view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4BS8.png)

The rest of my pages also seem to be unresponsive on mobile view.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @Malachi Bowman, Sometimes it happens to me that I forger the viewport: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Malachi Bowman, can I post it as an answer, so you can accept it? Thank you

Comment: @Violeta add it as an answer so that OP can accept it as soon as sees it and I can upvote for you :) Tag me blow in comment so that I am notified.

Comment: @ARK , thank you! You can check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Malachi Bowman,

Sometimes it happens to me that I forger the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

---

@ARK